# How do I scroll to the bottom of a div as data is added in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I'm writing a messenger application in Meteor, and I want to set it up such that when either user types a message it scrolls down to the bottom of the div for both of them. I am storing the message in a list called `messages` in a conversation document in the collection `Conversations`. I am using `cursor.observeChanges`, and it seems that the callback fires before the data is rendered on the client side so it doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom.

Here is the html:

```
<template name="chat">  
    {{> chatBox}}
</template>

<template name="chatBox">
    <div class="chat-box">
        <div id="chat-messages">
            {{#each chatMessages}}
                <div class="individual-message">
                    {{message}}
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
        <form id="chat-input">
            <input class="add-message" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Write something..." name="text" type="text">
      </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here's the relevant css:

```
#chat-messages {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 250px;
    height: 450px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And here's the js:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
    ...
    Conversations.find(conversationId).observeChanges({
      changed: function(id, fields){
         $("#chat-messages").scrollTop($("#chat-messages").prop("scrollHeight"));
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever I run into an issue where Blaze hasn't had a chance to render something in time for a Javascript function to be evoked on it, I use `Tracker.afterFlush`. This waits until the render cycle is done before running some code, e.g.:

```
// Inside a Meteor event callback
Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
  var $someItem = $('....');

  $(window).scrollTop($someItem.offset().top);
});
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_afterflush

Comment: @DavidKleiman Glad it helped! `Tracker.afterFlush` is one of the most important pro-tips I've ever gotten. :) It comes in handy on nearly every project.

Answer (score 0):

Different Approach via **tracking** of **Template helpers**:

I took advantage of the Template helper, as it **already tracks reactively all changes (and new) messages**. Hence, there you can place your scroll-down command.

I assume you have something like this in your JS file:

**chatBox.js**

```
Template.chatBox.helpers({
    chatMessages: function() {
       return Conversations.find({conversationId: conversationId},
      {sort: {d: -1}, limit: 20}).fetch().reverse();
    },
});
```

(Being `chatMessages.d` the **date** of posting and `conversationId` your reactive variable for the specific chat-room, sorted by date from the end, and displayed by reverse order, so that last chat would appear at the end of your `chat-messages div`, limited to the last 20 messages)

Just add your scroll-down command there, hence you would have:

```
Template.chatBox.helpers({
    chatMessages: function() {
       //scroll down not animated
       $('#chat-messages').scrollTop($('#chat-messages').prop('scrollHeight'));
       return Conversations.find({conversationId: conversationId},
      {sort: {d: -1}, limit: 20}).fetch().reverse();
    }
});
```

Or make it animated for smooth scrolling:

```
Template.chatBox.helpers({
    chatMessages: function() {
       //scroll down with animation
       $('#chat-messages').animate({scrollTop: $('#chat-messages').prop('scrollHeight')}, 500);
       return Conversations.find({conversationId: conversationId},
      {sort: {d: -1}, limit: 20}).fetch().reverse();
    }
});
```

This would trigger your "scroll-down" at any change in your Conversations-Collection.

Hope this helps.